# jQuery Sortable with Grouped Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

To start, here's a JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/RobGADV/kuy8wsLg/

```
<div class="tocButtonsDiv">
<div class="tocListItems">
    <div class="tocItemDiv">
        <div class="tocItem editTocTitle" data-pageid="51" data-title="Bacon Ipsum">Bacon Ipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tocItemDiv">
        <div class="tocItem editTocTitle" data-pageid="43" data-title="Pirate Ipsum">Pirate Ipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tocItemDiv">
        <div class="tocItem editTocTitle" data-pageid="48" data-title="Klingon Ipsum">Klingon Ipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tocSubListItems">
        <div class="tocSubItemDiv">
            <div class="tocSubItem editTocSubTitle" data-proposaltocid="8" data-title="klingon anchor">klingon anchor</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tocSubItemDiv">
            <div class="tocSubItem editTocSubTitle" data-proposaltocid="10" data-title="klingon anchor too">klingon anchor too</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tocItemDiv">
        <div class="tocItem editTocTitle" data-pageid="52" data-title="Plastic Onion Rings">Plastic Onion Rings</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tocSubListItems">
        <div class="tocSubItemDiv">
            <div class="tocSubItem editTocSubTitle" data-proposaltocid="11" data-title="Condiments">Condiments</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tocItemDiv">
        <div class="tocItem editTocTitle" data-pageid="53" data-title="Porcupines For Fun">Porcupines For Fun</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tocItemDiv">
        <div class="tocItem editTocTitle" data-pageid="54" data-title="Tragedy At 7-11">Tragedy At 7-11</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tocSubListItems">
        <div class="tocSubItemDiv">
            <div class="tocSubItem editTocSubTitle" data-proposaltocid="9" data-title="tragedy anchor">tragedy anchor</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tocItemDiv">
        <div class="tocItem editTocTitle" data-pageid="57" data-title="Something Fancy">Something Fancy</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Basically, I have a list of Items and Subitems, as you can see if you run the fiddle.  The larger boxes are the Items, the smaller boxes are subitems, grouped below its parent Item.  Make sense so far?

I want to be able to do the jqueryUI sortable() routine on each of the sets; meaning, I want to be able to reorder the Items (large buttons), and then also reorder the subItem (small buttons) under its parent Item.

I have the entire thing under a div called tocButtonsDiv.  Inside that is a div called tocListItems, which contains ALL of the Items ("tocItem") (and their respective subItems).

The way it is in the Fiddle right now is the only way it works at all, but it's not keeping the subItems with the parent, and in fact, treats the subitems as a single group (whether there's one, two or more).  I know my markup may need a little work, but I wonder if the .sortable() method has some more options I'm not aware of that will let me associate the subItems to the Items.

FWIW, the Fiddle as presented doesn't work at all; not sure why.  This is my first time actually using JSFiddle.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: for nested sortables need to define a `handle` on parent that isn't part of the sortable children

Comment: Can also find plugins for nested sortables

Comment: your fiddle is totally broken add url only for external scripts not the script tags

Comment: Reason your demo isn't working is you pasted script tags/link tags not url's into the external resources

Comment: The core part of the problem (and why the fiddle doesn't work) is because jQuery and jQuery UI aren't being included properly. In the include section you just need to post the URL, sans the `<script>` tags.